# Flash AS3 how to set the index of a button on the stage?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have about 60 buttons added manually to the timeline. I need to specify the index of each but the index is given depending on the order I drop the object on the stage from the library.
I dont want to have to specify each button's index programmatically by name since there is no easy pattern to follow.

```
private function buttonHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            event.target.parent.getChildIndex(event.target));
}
```

I can get all the indexes like this but they are not in the order I want.
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

To change the order of the index manually, use `addChildAt (DisplayObject, index)` 
if you want Two displayobject index switch. please use the following. `swapChildren(DisplayObject1,DisplayObject2)` `swapChildrenAt(index1,index2)`

If you look at the image below, there is the instance MovieClip 6 in stage. but the index is arbitrary. depends on really creating order or drag&drop order from libary. so i'm re-ordering index by name according to the order.

[image]

```
import flash.display.MovieClip;

var mc:MovieClip;
for(var i:int = 0; i<this.numChildren; i++)
{
    mc = this.getChildAt(i) as MovieClip;
    trace("before clipName: " + mc.name);
}

//re-ordering
for(i = 0; i<this.numChildren; i++)
{
    mc = this.getChildByName("mc"+i) as MovieClip;
    addChildAt(mc,i);
}

for(i = 0; i<this.numChildren; i++)
{
    mc = this.getChildAt(i) as MovieClip;
    trace("after clipName: " + mc.name);
}
```

---

```
console:

before clipName: mc1
before clipName: mc4
before clipName: mc3
before clipName: mc5
before clipName: mc2
before clipName: mc0

after clipName: mc0
after clipName: mc1
after clipName: mc2
after clipName: mc3
after clipName: mc4
after clipName: mc5
```